# Can a 32 bit daemon be run on 64 bit linux

Tags: linux, daemon

A simple question (maybe) can a daemon coded and compiled as 32-bit be run on a 64-bit linux distro? I haven't seen the info anywhere where it can't be.

Comment: Your major problem will be that the distro will probably only have a very minimal set of 32-bit libraries available.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run 32-bit processes on a 64-bit Linux system.  There's nothing special about daemons.

Answer (score 0):

It depends both on architecture support (i.e. executing both 64-bit and 32-bit code) and on specific linux support (providing system calls to both 64-bit and 32-bit code). For amd64 linux, both are true. See, for example:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch

Similarly, ARMv8 supports both 32-bit and 64-bit modes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMv8#ARMv8_and_64-bit
http://www.arm.com/files/downloads/ARMv8_Architecture.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As long as the shared libraries are available in 32-bit, then a 32-bit daemon will run on a 64-bit Linux.